# Put an image over capture image from camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios7, uiimageview

Hi I am working on an app in which i will take the photo from camera and then places images like glasses,hairs etc on it.Can anyone let me know how it is done.I have to save that image as well.Was surfing on internet but can not find any thing related.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apple's '[Detecting Faces in an Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html)' found in Core Image Programming Guide. Getting the face and face feature bounds includes left eye, right eye and mouth - x and y positions. Once you have those, it's a matter of adding a subview to the desired coordinates with any picture you like (glasses for example).

Depending on the distance between the mouth and the eyes, you can probably come up with some average distance to the top of the head if you want to add hair. Trial and error.